# Find if value exists using SQL True/False Return

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net

**Aim:** To Assess if one, or more, examples of a value exists in a Database in the quickest time as I only needs a True/False result.

The variable is Alphanumeric.

**Question:** Is this the quickest and best way to do this?

```
Public Function PrcCheckIfValueExists(vVariable As String) As String
        'Here we check if the Value Exists in the database 
        Try
            Dim ConnectionString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SQLLocal").ToString()
            Using connection = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
                Using command As New SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM TblTable WHERE ID= '" & vVariable & "'", connection)
                    connection.Open()
                    Dim result = command.ExecuteScalar()
                    connection.Close()
                    If result = "" Then
                        Return False
                    Else
                        Return True
                    End If
                End Using
            End Using

        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try

    End Function
```

Comment: Why does the code return Booleans when the signature suggests it should return a string?

Comment: Incoming is string outgoing is variable. Should I use As Boolean as last part of the first line?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. This code is open to [injection](http://xkcd.com/327/). Consider
   what happens if I pass `sometext'; Drop Table TblTable; --` into
   that variable. Use a proper parameterized query instead.
2. The SQL statement itself is about as efficient as it can be to my
   knowledge. A count would add extra overhead. Using an `Exists` might
   garner you a negligible amount of performance at the cost of
   readability. (`Exists` wouldn't need to return any value at all
   except what you tell it.)
3. You could simplify your return statement by using [`IsNullOrEmpty()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx)

Instead of:

```
                If result = "" Then
                    Return False
                Else
                    Return True
                End If
```

You could just use this:

```
Return Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(result)
```

Comment: no Semi-Colons in VB...LOL

Comment: Also you need to add a `Not` in there to keep the false return value on empty string.

Answer (score 10):

You should use `Command parameters` instead of string concatenation to avoid `SQL injection attacks`

```
 command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.NVarChar) ' this might not be the appropriate type
 command.Parameters("@ID").Value = vVariable
```

The connection will be closed after the `using` statement, so you don't need to close it explicitly

```
connection.Close() 'delete this line, it is redundant
```

`vVariable` is not good for a variable name, because every variable is a variable, ID might be a good choice here

Comment: I should of mentioned the value derived from clicking on a value however I will change it for good practice, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In your SQL, use [EXISTS](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/special-operators/sql_exists.php) instead of `TOP 1 ID`.  It might be faster, but would probably be impossible to measure the difference.  But it better expresses what you are interested in.  And it certainly won't be slower.

Answer (score 2):

The safer way to do this is to actually call a stored procedure.

### Separation of Concerns.

This is the line of code that I am talking about

```
Using command As New SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM TblTable WHERE ID= '" & vVariable & "'", connection)
```

The code doesn't need to know how the database query is retrieving the information.

The stored procedure will run just as efficiently or faster, because the database will know about the procedure before it is run and have a "game plan" for it before it is called.

The variable should stay a variable all the way to the stored procedure.

---

you can remove the `connection.Close()` and move the if statement outside of the Try Catch like this

```
Try
    Dim ConnectionString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SQLLocal").ToString()
    Using connection = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        Using command As New SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM TblTable WHERE ID= '" & vVariable & "'", connection)
            connection.Open()
            Dim result = command.ExecuteScalar()
        End Using
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    Return False
End Try
If result = "" Then 
    Return False
Else
    Return True
End If
```

or you can get rid of the if else and the variable declaration altogether

```
Try
    Dim ConnectionString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SQLLocal").ToString()
    Using connection = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        connection.Open()
        Using command As New SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM TblTable WHERE ID= '" & vVariable & "'", connection)
            Return Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(command.ExecuteScalar()) 
        End Using
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    Return False
End Try
```

You will save a little bit when you nix the Variable creation

---

---

I somewhat agree with MrCochese.

If the code was returning a list of information with no input parameters needed, then I would say just use the string, but this code is asking for a very specific piece of information and needs a piece of input.

The code(application) gathers the input, sends it to the database. The database looks for the specified piece of information and returns it to the code(application).  This shows a separation of concerns (there are two things happening here), input and query.

In the example of returning a simple set of information, only one things is happening, the return of information.  There is no input or place for injection to occur.

so I stand by what I said about using a stored procedure, or better yet a user defined function because only one specific piece of information is being returned

Comment: This is a horrible idea, as you're just introduced an external dependency that is not versioned with your code. Don't do this - let SQL do the job it was created for.

Comment: @MrCochese, Which idea are you saying is horrible?

Comment: @MrCochese - he is no less dependent upon the TblTable schema, which is not necessarily versioned with his code.  Quite the opposite - if you treat a procedure as a public API and maintain its interface, a DBA is free to change the underlying schema without requiring code changes.

Comment: You're never going to need any of that. It's not an API, it's a database.

Comment: The SQL is still doing the SQL stuff, I left the Query String in the code because that is what the OP has there. I mentioned the fact that there should be a stored procedure on the database that is called using a parameter, that still stands. I haven't taken anything away from the database, it's really the opposite I have given back to the database what should rightfully be there @MrCochese

Comment: Data should be in the database. Seeing people abuse stored procedures like this - especially to obfuscate a one line query, for Heaven's sake - makes me a sad panda.

Comment: @MrCochese If the schema changes in a way that the sproc needs to change, it could be changed without OP recompiling the code. That's why stored procedures are there to begin with.

Comment: Why would the schema change if not in reaction to the needs of the application? Again you're preparing for scenarios that would never happen in real life. Is this just about the imaginary performance boost from execution plan caching that hasn't been true in decades?

Comment: @MrCochese Databases often run more than one application. I don't want to pollute the answer further, so if you want to discuss this, feel free to ping me in [the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor).

Comment: @MrCochese, where is your review of this question? it seems that you disagree with what a majority of people think about using SQL Query strings in their code, I would love to see your detailed answer to this question, and why any of these answers are wrong.

Comment: Disagree with the majority - That's a pretty massive stretch, wouldn't you say? Fortunately, the accepted answer is pretty much spot on. Incidentally, I just noticed that your catch block returns false, even though the connection might simply have timed out. That's not a great idea either.

Comment: @MrCochese, now you are picking apart the OP's code.  The Catch returning false is OP code.

Comment: Well, it is Code Review!

Comment: @MrCochese - Then maybe you could post it as a comment under the correct portion, so the OP might have a better chance of being notified/reading it.